# JQUERY show hide FIELDSET depending on RADIO BUTTON

Tags: jquery, radio-button, hide, show, fieldset

I wanna use JQUERY to show and hide some fieldset inside a form in this way:

PSEUDOCODE:

```
- if user-type == Company: show("company-fieldset")

- if user-type == Individual:
         - if individual-type == Freelancer: show("freelancer-fieldset")
         - if individual-type == Professor: show("professor-fieldset")
         - if individual-type == Student: show("student-fieldset")
```

I'm new in using JQUERY but I need a fast way to accomplish this thing, I'll really appreciate if you can help me. Please take into account that:
 I have to use radio buttons because they're mutual exclusive.
 Everytime I select a radio-button the form must update real time.
Thanks

HTML

```
<form method="POST">

  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <input type="radio" id="user-type" value="company" checked>Company<br>
    <input type="radio" id="user-type" value="individual">Individual<br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="company-fieldset">
    <p>Company showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="individual-fieldset">
    <p>Individual showed!</p>
    <input type="radio" id="individual-type" value="freelancer" checked>Freelancer<br>
    <input type="radio" id="individual-type" value="professor">Professor<br>
    <input type="radio" id="individual-type" value="student" >Student<br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="freelancer-fieldset">
    <p>Freelancer showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="professor-fieldset">
    <p>Professor showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="student-fieldset">
    <p>Student showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello World!')">SUBMIT</button>
  </fieldset>

 </form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#user-type').change(function() {

        var user_type = $(this).attr("value");

        if (user_type === "Company") {
            $('.company-fieldset').show();
            $('.freelancer-fieldset').hide();
            $('.professor-fieldset').hide();
            $('.student-fieldset').hide();
        }

        if (user_type === "Individual") {
            $('.company-fieldset').hide();
            if (user_type === "Freelancer") {
                $('.freelancer-fieldset').show();
                $('.professor-fieldset').hide();
                $('.student-fieldset').hide();
            }
            if (user_type === "Professor") {
                $('.freelancer-fieldset').hide();
                $('.professor-fieldset').show();
                $('.student-fieldset').hide();
            }
            if (user_type === "Student") {
                $('.freelancer-fieldset').dide();
                $('.professor-fieldset').hide();
                $('.student-fieldset').show();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No jQuery required here, a little reformat of your HTML and a small sprinkle of CSS.

- I added a name to your radios so that they are grouped by type
- I put the fieldsets after the radio that controls them.

```css
fieldset:not(.main-fieldset) {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + br + fieldset {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">

  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <input type="radio" id="user-type" name='user-type' value="company" checked>Company
    <br>
    <fieldset class="company-fieldset">
      <p>Company showed!</p>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="radio" id="user-type" name='user-type' value="individual">Individual
    <br>
    <fieldset class="individual-fieldset">
      <p>Individual showed!</p>
      <input type="radio" id="individual-type" name="individual-type" value="freelancer" checked>Freelancer
      <br>
      <fieldset class="freelancer-fieldset">
        <p>Freelancer showed!</p>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="radio" id="individual-type" name="individual-type" value="professor">Professor
      <br>
      <fieldset class="professor-fieldset">
        <p>Professor showed!</p>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="radio" id="individual-type" name="individual-type" value="student">Student
      <br>
      <fieldset class="student-fieldset">
        <p>Student showed!</p>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello World!')">SUBMIT</button>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

**EDIT:** 
If you can nest the fieldsets in the same parent (looks like you can)

```css
fieldset:not(.main-fieldset) {
  display: none;
}
input[value=company]:checked ~ fieldset[class^=company] {
  display: block;
}
input[value=individual]:checked ~ fieldset[class^=individual] {
  display: block;
}
input[value=freelancer]:checked ~ fieldset[class^=freelancer] {
  display: block;
}
input[value=professor]:checked ~ fieldset[class^=professor] {
  display: block;
}
input[value=student]:checked ~ fieldset[class^=student] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">

  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <input type="radio" name="user-type" value="company" checked>Company
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="user-type" value="individual">Individual
    <br>
    <fieldset class="company-fieldset">
      <p>Company showed!</p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="individual-fieldset">
      <p>Individual showed!</p>
      <input type="radio" name="individual-type" value="freelancer" checked>Freelancer
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="individual-type" value="professor">Professor
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="individual-type" value="student">Student
      <br>
      <fieldset class="freelancer-fieldset">
        <p>Freelancer showed!</p>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="professor-fieldset">
        <p>Professor showed!</p>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="student-fieldset">
        <p>Student showed!</p>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello World!')">SUBMIT</button>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

**EDIT:** if you really must keep the same HTML then jQuery will be required.  NOTE: I still had to provide your radio buttons names to make them mutually exclusive.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $("fieldset:not(.main-fieldset)").hide();//hide everything
      $(this).parent().show();//show this ones container
      $("fieldset[class^='" + $(this).val() + "']").show(); //show the matching fieldset
      $("fieldset[class^='" + $(this).val() + "']>input:checked").change();//show children as required.
    }
  });
  $("input[value=company]").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">

  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <input type="radio" name="user-type" value="company" checked>Company<br>
    <input type="radio" name="user-type" value="individual">Individual<br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="company-fieldset">
    <p>Company showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="individual-fieldset">
    <p>Individual showed!</p>
    <input type="radio" name="individual-type" value="freelancer" checked>Freelancer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="individual-type" value="professor">Professor<br>
    <input type="radio" name="individual-type" value="student" >Student<br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="freelancer-fieldset">
    <p>Freelancer showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="professor-fieldset">
    <p>Professor showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="student-fieldset">
    <p>Student showed!</p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello World!')">SUBMIT</button>
  </fieldset>

 </form>
```

Comment: Ok I really thank you Steve but I still want to use jquery because actually my radio buttons are not manually created by me, but they're coming from the Flask WTFORM library, so they cannot be scorporated each others. Take a look:

Comment: user_type = RadioField('User Type:*', validators=[Required()],
                           choices=[('company', 'Company'),
                                    ('individual', 'Individual')],
                           default='company')

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library in question, are you saying you do not have control of the outputted HTML?  Are the radio buttons going to be properly grouped?

Comment: I will add another edit shortly that will work if you absolutely need to keep the existing HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">

        <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
            {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email() }}
            {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password() }}
            {{ form.phone.label }} {{ form.phone() }}
            {{ form.location.label }} {{ form.location() }}
            {{ form.user_type.label }} {{ form.user_type(id='user-type') }}
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="company-fieldset">
            {{ form.company_name.label }} {{ form.company_name() }}
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="individual-fieldset">
            {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}
            {{ form.surname.label }} {{ form.surname() }}
            {{ form.birth.label }} {{ form.birth() }}
            {{ form.skills.label }} {{ form.skills() }}
            {{ form.individual_type.label }} {{ form.individual_type(id='individual-type') }}

            <fieldset class="freelancer-fieldset">
                {{ form.studio.label }} {{ form.studio() }}
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="professor-fieldset">
                {{ form.department.label }} {{ form.department() }}
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="student-fieldset">
                {{ form.school.label }} {{ form.school() }}
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="main-fieldset">
            {{ form.submit() }}
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my JS looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#user_type, #individual_type").change(function() {

        var user_type = $('#user_type').attr("value");

        if (user_type == "company") {
            $('.company-fieldset').show();
            $('.individual-fieldset').hide();
        }

        if (user_type == "individual") {

            $('.company-fieldset').hide();

            var individual_type = $('#individual_type').attr("value");

            if (individual_type == "freelancer") {
                $('.freelancer-fieldset').show();
                $('.professor-fieldset').hide();
                $('.student-fieldset').hide();
            }
            if (individual_type == "professor") {
                $('.freelancer-fieldset').hide();
                $('.professor-fieldset').show();
                $('.student-fieldset').hide();
            }
            if (individual_type == "student") {
                $('.freelancer-fieldset').hide();
                $('.professor-fieldset').hide();
                $('.student-fieldset').show();
            }
        }
    })
});
```